# Inverse z transform using partial fraction expansion in scilab?

Tags: matlab, scilab

I am new to scilab. so far I have understood Scilab is like MATLAB. In Matlab inbuilt functions are there in order to calculate inverse z transform using partial fraction expansion. Is there any function in scilab in order to perform inverse z transform using partial fraction expansion or can you provide me the code of inverse z transform using partial fraction expansion in scilab?

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab the `iztrans` functions operates on symbolic expressions, which is not possible in Scilab. However, in Scilab you can manipulate rational fractions (with floating point coefficients, `help rational`) and compute their partial fraction expansion (`help pfss`). This would be then your job to consider individual terms of the expansion.